# About potentiometer principle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

We know we give a battery connection. current wiil be determined by the resistance. if the resistance is too high then current will be low. but current will pass through.
then in potentiometer , why potential drop per length is fixed? different voltage should have diffrent voltage drop per length.
please answer it.

Answer (score 0):

The voltage between the ends of the potentiometer wire should be only slightly less than the emf, $\mathscr E$, of the cell or voltage source across which it is connected. It will be slightly less because of the voltage drop, $Ir$, across the internal resistance, $r$, of the source. But this doesn't matter because $\mathscr E$ and $Ir$, and therefore the pd, $\mathscr E - Ir$, across the potentiometer wire, will be almost constant over the time that the potentiometer is being used.

Constancy (over time) of the pd across the potentiometer wire is all that matters because that implies that the potential drop per unit length, $v$, is constant. We find its value (that is we *calibrate* the potentiometer) by determining the balance length, $\ell_0$, for a source of known emf $\mathscr E_0$ inserted as the voltage to be measured. This gives us $v=\mathscr E_0 /\ell_0$.